# Cross validation of survival model

Tags: r, survival-analysis

I am trying to estimate AUC for survival models using the package survAUC. After running the code I get an error:

```
Error in AUC.hc(Surv.rsp, Surv.rsp.new, lpnew, times) : 
NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 6)
```

What might be the reason for this error and how can i remove it? My code is:

```
head(duration)
  Event_ID      Time Status Season Time_of_day
1        1       15      1      1           0
2        2       30      1      0           1
3        3       15      1      1           0
4        4       15      1      0           0
5        5       45      1      0           1
6        6      105      1      0           1
TR<-duration[1:2176,]
TE<-duration[2177:6528,]
clearance5<-survreg(Surv(duration$Time)~Season+Time_of_day,data = duration,dist = 'weibull',na.action=na.omit)
lpnew<-predict(clearance5,TE)
Surv.rsp<-Surv(TR$Time)
Surv.rsp.new<-Surv(TE$Time)
times<-seq(60,90,105)
auc_hc<-AUC.hc(Surv.rsp,Surv.rsp.new,lpnew,times)
```

Comment: We have no way to look at your copy of the object `duration`

Comment: I'm not sure if this is causing your error, but `times<-seq(60,90,105)` results in a single value (60) for `times`, which probably isn't what you intended. `seq(60, 90, 105)` means you want values from 60 to 90 separated by 105 units. Did you mean you wanted 105 values from 60 to 90? If so, use `length.out=105`.

Comment: @42 I have added how the object duration looks like

Comment: Thanks@eipi10  I have tried to modify the code as you suggested but it seems like that is not the reason for the error.

Comment: There is no column named `Time` in your "duration"-object, so the first `Surv` function should have been be throwing an error about a missing object. This is starting to look like a request for "code review". You should be posting a full console session starting from the first line of code. And perhaps posting in the Code Review section of the stackexchange family of sites. (The first error is usually the one you need to fix, not the last one.)

Comment: Thanks for your reply@42,i did not intend for a code review, but excuse me for missing the "Duration" instead of "Time" as i was trying to format the object in a way that can be easily understood. I will appreciate if you will take a look of the problem again.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the following code should works:

```
library(survival)
library(survAUC)

duration <- na.omit(duration)
TR <- duration[1:2176,]
TE <- duration[2177:6528,]

clearance5 <- survreg(Surv(Time, Status) ~ Season+Time_of_day,
                 data = TR, dist='weibull', na.action=na.omit)
lpnew <- predict(clearance5, newdata=TE)
Surv.rsp <- Surv(TR$Time, TR$Status)
Surv.rsp.new <- Surv(TE$Time, TE$Status)
times <- c(60,90,105)
auc_hc <- AUC.hc(Surv.rsp, Surv.rsp.new, lpnew, times)
```